# How to fix " MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox" could not be resolved

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, material-design-in-xaml

I am trying to make an UI with material design but when I want to use it I have an error: **The resource " MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox" could not be resolved.**

https://ibb.co/PcvdmqH how the error looks like

I installed from NuGet MaterialDesignThemes 
I imported this  `xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"`

And in App.xaml I wrote this:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="MaterialDesign">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Indigo.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need a clean solution and rebuild after adding the code to App.xaml

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this on the top of your xaml file where you want to put  the textbox with style materialdesignfloatinghint style

xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"

Answer (score 0):

Try to also add the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your project resources, that you have the nugets for Material Design.
Add this code in your App.Xaml file; under Application.Resources.
It works for me.
`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />`